# Math PhD Applications: Is it better to show just my good GRE score, or should I also send my low initial score?

Tags: phd, application, united-states, gre

I am applying for mathematics PhD programs in the United States.

I did not major in mathematics as an undergrad and I did not do so well the first time around on the GRE Math subject test (about 60th percentile). I have since completed a Master's in mathematics and my score has improved to about 90th percentile.

I think it could benefit me to send both scores since it shows my progress. Will admissions committees in general view this in a positive light? Or should I just send my most recent good score.

Comment: Just send your best one. I can't see an advantage in documenting progress through comparing 2 scores. You'll apply at your current level, and that's what matters.

Comment: What's more impressive: winning the Super Bowl two years in a row, or missing the playoffs one year and winning the Super Bowl the next?

Comment: Depending upon how long ago you took it the first time, that score might not even be good any more anyway. Schools will typically only accept back a limited number of years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send your best one. GRE is typically used simply as a filter and including your lower score will probably hurt you more than it helps.

Answer (score -2):

As I recall, in my day at least one could not choose which scores were sent. A complete history of scores was sent with a score report.

Comment: This is not the case anymore. You can choose which score report to send. Schools won't even know about any scores that you choose not to send to them. This incentivizes people to take the GRE as many times as possible so ETS can make that ca$$$$$$h

Comment: Please see [this ETS GRE web page](http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/?WT.ac=grehome_grescores_150213): The ScoreSelect® option lets you decide which test scores to send to the institutions you designate.